# MySQL: Update values for multiple rows under the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this table wherein it has columns named AMEX and CashOnly. Both of them have values of either 1 or 0. Now, instead of 1 and 0, I want to change all the '1' values to 'YES' and all the '0' values to 'NO' so it would be much more understandable to the viewer.

What is the most efficient SQL query I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: What are the types of your `AMEX` and `CashOnly` columns?

Comment: AMEX and CashOnly are set to int. After changing it to varchar, what should be the proper "UPDATE" query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET AMEX     = CASE WHEN AMEX = '0'     THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END,
    CashOnly = CASE WHEN CashOnly = '0' THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
```

Note that this assumes that you have converted your `AMEX` and `CashOnly` columns to `VARCHAR`.  Also note that there is no `WHERE` clause because you want to update all records in your table.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it gave an error saying "#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'SET CashOnly = CASE
    WHEN CashOnly = '0' THEN 'NO'
    ELSE 'YES'
    END' Ã  la ligne 6

Comment: @lexus Sorry I had an extra `SET` statement in there.  It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `case` statement:

```
select (case when AMEX = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as AMEX,
       (case when cash = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as cash
. . .
```

Comment: Hi, it worked, however, it only selected the field entries and not really changed the value. I think the proper keyword should be "UPDATE" but I am not sure about the syntax on how to use it for this kind of issue.

Comment: Use a view instead.  Don't change the values.  The existing value is an integer and you want to change it to a character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your column type then you need to do following: (As int field can't store yes/no as value)

create 2 extra enum field name them whatever you want for now. let them be amex1 and cash1. declare their values as 'yes', 'no' set default value as no.

Now execute following 2 queries one by one.

```
UPDATE table_name SET amex1 = 'yes' WHERE amex = 1;
UPDATE table_name SET cash1 = 'yes' WHERE cash = 1;
```

Now delete cash and amex column rename cash1 and amex1 to cash and amex respectively. hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
update table set amex=(case when AMEX = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) ,
CashOnly=(case when CashOnly= 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end);
```

OR

```
update table set amex='Yes' where amex=1;
update table set amex='No' where amex=0;
update table set CashOnly='Yes' where CashOnly=1;
update table set CashOnly='No' where CashOnly=0;
```